# How to show JSON data in fragments?

Tags: android, json, listview, fragment

I have four swipeable fragments on an activity in tabbed view mode.Each fragment should show JSON data from an API.
There are two problems
The first  problem is that only in first fragment I am able to get the data.
And the second problem is that when swiping to next fragment I lost the data received in the first fragment.
I have four layouts for each of the  fragment.
I am using custom listview to show the data.

*After creating fragment and getting theJSON data I am using custom list view to show it in the first fragment using aeroFirst method as below but I am not able to do the same in the other fragment.  Creating fragments,JSON parsing and aeroFirst method are all in MainActivityclass *

snip of the code

```
                private void aeroFirst(List<Details> mList) {
    //   layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);


    for (Details bean : details) {
        final String urlChar = bean.getUrl();

        if (bean.getResType().equals("Videos"))

        {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, mList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Click ListItem Number " + urlChar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
```

Comment: Create a manager class as singleton,store API response in manager and access response  from your fragment.

Answer (score 2):

There must be an activity behind all four fragments, right?  Store the values in that activity so that all four fragments can access the JSONs.  This might not be the best in style, but the other solution involves saving it into [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or similar approach.

Another way to do this is to load everything in the activity, and then put the JSONs into [arguments as bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) for each fragment.

Comment: Storing list items in Shared preferences is a very bad idea.

Comment: I am using a single API to fetch data and before fetching I am using if statement to differentiate different types of data in the API.

Comment: @ReazMurshed storing list items in Shared preferences is a very bad idea, so I do not recommend it.  I think the best way is to store it somewhere as a static field in the activity that hosts all four fragments.